# How to pass a string from javascript to server? and then get a return value from server in asp.net webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this modal. inside a form tag

```
<div id="Incoming_Call" class="modal fade" role="document">
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="Caller_id" Text="Incoming Call"</asp:Label>
</div>
```

I want to change the label text when the modal will show

```
<script> 
string id = "temporary value"//javascript has this value on clientside.
// i don't have this value on page load but after some event triggers.

$('#Incoming_call').on('shown', function(){
    id="zetawars@hotmail.com";
    var text  = '<%= generatestring(id)%>';
    $('#<%=Caller_id.ClientID%>').html = id;
});
</script>
```

I need to send that `id` variable to server side to a function `generateString()` after the string has changed from `id="temporary Value"` to  `id="zetwars@hotmail.com"` or something

This is on server side.

```
public string generateString(string id)
{
     id = // does some processing;
     return id;
 }
```

So, I want to send a variable of javascript to the server side then server has to do some processing and return the value. the javascript variable is not ready at page load time. So I can't pass it inside `<%%>` these tags and get a newer value. It will only pass "temporary value" as a string not the new value.

Comment: I think the only way to do this is Reloading the page with a post value or something, or maybe Ajax can help with reloading only 1 section of your site. I wanted to do the same, but end up reloading the page after new value arrive.

Comment: you need to use the [Request.Form Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: There are many ways, [webmethods](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) might be simplest to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a server side method from javascript is really simple.You can do this with jQuery `$.ajax` function and a `[WebMethod]`

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string generateString(string id)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    return String.Format("Response from server for - {0}.Call time - {1}",id,DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var id = "temporary value";

            $("#btnMakeAjaxCall").click(function () {
                MakeAjaxCall();
            });

            function MakeAjaxCall() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AjaxCallExample.aspx/generateString",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: '{id:"' + id + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var caller = '<%: Caller_id.ClientID %>';
                        $("#" + caller).text(data.d)
                    },
                    error: function (errordata) {
                        console.log(errordata);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="button" id="btnMakeAjaxCall" value="Make AJAX call" />
        <asp:Label ID="Caller_id" runat="server" Text="Incoming Call"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thnkx it worked. i also had to use a webservice though.

Comment: also i hav a question. how you get data.d? what is d? where did you define it?
$("#" + caller).text(data.d)

Comment: `data.d` is coming from Microsoft's implementation of web methods. It is a security feature to require access to the data through a property. They had to choose something, they choose `d`

Comment: thnkx for the info

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call to server and use the returned value.
you can make ajax call each time the modal is shown
or
you can make ajax call whenever you are ready to get result from server, this way you can make ajax call and store the result in a hidden variable on page or some other already defined variable and use the variable in modal.

jQuery code to make ajax call to server
To make ajax call you need to add reference to jQuery in your page.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/controller_name/method_name",
        type: "POST",
        data: { var1:var1},
        success: function (response) {
           //use response here

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Some unexpected error occured. Please try again.");
        }
    });
```

This is the way you can accomplish what you want, lets us know id you need help in coding also.

Comment: i need help. if you can give me an example

Comment: I am using webforms. what is the controller here. i have code on the master page. patient.Master.
and how should the function be called?
modal.on(shown function(){
// here?

})
 how does it return the value?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ajax%20call%20asp.net%20web%20froms http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/jQuery/318_Doing_AJAX_with_jQuery_in_ASPNet.aspx